# two divs in one div with img in each two, how to autoresize but keep row formation?

Tags: html, css, resize, row, autoresize

I've put two divs (with one image in each) in one principal div. How can I make the CSS to autoresize both divs (with images) to fit size browser but keep the row formation?

The issue with my code is that, the images autoresize but divs will turn in column formation.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6Uhe8/)

*HTML :*

```
<div id="test">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="a.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <img src="b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#test{ width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: please post your code (HTML/CSS) to get a proper answer.

Comment: i don't have yet an css code. I just wanna know de css code to integrate in html because what i have right now, is a mess :)

Comment: Can u show that in visual representation

Comment: Or, let's say like this, i have:
#test{
width:100%;
height:100%;}


<div id="test">
<div style="display:inline-block"><img src="a.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block"><img src="b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
</div>

Comment: I want to keep row formation of this two divs when i resize the browser window and the divs/imgs  too

Comment: please put your code in your question and use jsfiddle or codepen  if you want some help/advise :so  http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/8GSqB/ what have you started to try to do from here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/pZZN8/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="test">
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-10.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#test div{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#test div img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: SUPERB!!! THank you so much! Is exactly what i've searched all day :)

One other question, can i put this code without the FLoat function? This divs will be putted right to one div that is already floaded left :D

Comment: This is the code that i use now, that from you. Another thing, how can i put in this code... a space between the two divs? If i put padding or margin, will get in column formation :(

Comment: @PickOne I think he has solved the issue for this question, and if you have another one, than you should ask a different question

Comment: @PickOne And also make sure that you mark the answer as helpful by clicking on the tick on the left side of this answer below the upvote and downvote arrows, this will help future visitors to refer...